# Eclipse: "Edit Source Lookup Path..."

Tags: android, eclipse, android-source

I am developing on a Mac with Eclipse and have the skeleton for an app that implements the standard framework callbacks (onCreate, onDestroy, onPause, etc..). When I set breakpoints in the callbacks the debugger stops and displays a tab that says:

> ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread
>   $ActivityRecord,Intent)line:2477

And in the tab page body there is some red text that says "Source not found" and a button that says "Edit Source Lookup Path...".

I have tried adding several paths via "Edit Source Lookup Path..." but I can't seem to find the one Eclipse is looking for.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your program has stopped inside Android code. Often these internal errors (null pointers etc) are caused by a mistake in your code, but the error reporting isn't there, instead you get an internal crash.

However it can help a lot sometimes to view the Android source code. This can be done fairly easily.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to debug/run , it will redirect to Edit Source Lookup page.At this time, we need to point to the java source code by clicking on Add button (Java Project)

Refer the screenshot

[image]

[image]